# Find documents whose array field contains at least n elements of a given array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

It is basically what the title says.

Input: `myArray` = an array of words

I have an model that have field 
`wordsCollection` , which is an array field.

How can I find all documents of that model whose `wordsCollections` has at least n elements of `myArray`

Comment: Show db structure and what yo have tried so far to make it work.

Comment: I dont think the question is clear enough that I don't need to provide the db structure. I am not sure whether mongodb provides such an API call, so I am just thinking about iterating through all the documents.... Of course, it sounds really bad

Comment: Are the items of `myArray` and `wordsCollection` unique?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let say we have the following documents in our collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759658e654456bf4a014d01"), "a" : [ 1, 3, 9, 2, 9, 0 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759658e654456bf4a014d02"), "a" : [ 0, 8, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759658e654456bf4a014d03"), "a" : [ 0, 8, 432, 9, 34, -3 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759658e654456bf4a014d04"), "a" : [ 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7 ] }
```

and the following input array and `n = 2`

```
var inputArray = [1, 3, 0];
```

We can return those documents where the array field contains at least n elements of a given array using the aggregation framework.

The [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) selects only those documents with the array's length greater or equals to `n`. This reduce the amount of data to be processed in down in the pipeline.

The [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline operator use a logical condition processing using the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator and the special operations [`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) to "discard" the document where the condition is false.

In our case, the condition is [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) which returns true if the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the intersection of the two arrays, which we compute using the [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator is greater than or equal `2`.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$match": { "a.1": { "$exists": true } } }, 
        { "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [ 
                { "$gte": [ 
                    { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$a", inputArray ] } }, 
                    2
                ]},
                "$$KEEP", 
                "$$PRUNE" 
            ]
        }}
    ]
)
```

which produces:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759658e654456bf4a014d01"), "a" : [ 1, 3, 9, 2, 9, 0 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759658e654456bf4a014d02"), "a" : [ 0, 8, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759658e654456bf4a014d04"), "a" : [ 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7 ] }
```

Comment: Your solution is amazing. I learn a lot of mongodb from it. Thks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation.

In [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation pipeline, you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/)

Comment: I'm gonna try, that could be pretty usefull if it's work to avoid keep updating "count" field! Dunno why you got downvoted tho, I upvote back

Comment: @libik: I'll give it a try

Comment: You can't use `$size` in `$match` here. I failed to see how this solve the problem in hand here. Btw @JulienLeray, you don't upvote an answer just because it has been downvoted.  Vote based on content's quality.