# MongoDB: Using an array to find value in array atribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have the following code

```
//My search array
var charArray=['a','b','c']

{
    name: 'object1',
    myChar: ['a','v','x']
}

{
    name: 'object2',
    myChar: ['f','h','y']
}
```

I want to get the object which contains a value in its attribute.

I hope to get the first object using this:

```
db.getCollection('myObjects').find({
    'myChar':{
        $in:charArray
    }
})
```

The response is null. In fact I tried using $elemMatch without success

```
db.getCollection('myObjects').find({
    'myChar':{
        $elemMatch: {$in: charArray}
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you add the expected response to the post ?

Comment: {
    name: 'object1',
    myChar: ['a','v','x']
}

Comment: did you run the query again ? It should give you the expected response.

Comment: Yes, but the response is 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find documents whose array field contains at least n elements of a given array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725694/find-documents-whose-array-field-contains-at-least-n-elements-of-a-given-array)

Answer (score -1):

I thing you have a typo because I replicate your situation in mongodb instance and your $elemMatch solution works just fine.