# mongoengine - use pipeline to find a match between 2 arrays

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I need to make a query on MongoDB using `mongoengine`

I have a document that contains a list of groups:
`groups = ['groupa', 'groupb'...]`

In addition, I have a list of other groups `my_groups= ['groupc', 'groupd', 'groupc'...]`

The wanted result is to find all documents that have any match between those arrays.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725694) but it is not via `mongoengine`

How can I do that via `mongoengine`?

Comment: What to you mean by *any match*?  Do you mean Intersection?

Comment: correct @Styvane

Comment: You need to use the [`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate) method to do this as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725694/find-documents-whose-array-field-contains-at-least-n-elements-of-a-given-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find documents whose array field contains at least n elements of a given array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725694/find-documents-whose-array-field-contains-at-least-n-elements-of-a-given-array)

Comment: I noticed that question, but it did not help me I did not success that via `mongoengine`

Comment: Please update your question with your query.

Comment: I did not succeed to create that query with `mongoengine` that is the issue

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy to adapt pure MongoDB query to Mongoengine. Assuming that your collection is named `Foo`, field is named `groups` and the list that your comparing with is assigned to variable `my_groups` the query from the [mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725694/find-documents-whose-array-field-contains-at-least-n-elements-of-a-given-array) will look like this

```
Foo.objects.aggregate(*[ 
             { "$match": { "groups.1": { "$exists": True } } }, 
             { "$redact": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                     { "$gte": [ 
                         { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$groups", my_groups ] } }, 
                         1
                     ]},
                     "$$KEEP", 
                     "$$PRUNE" 
                 ]
             }}
         ])
```

Please note the asterisk before the list argument.

Comment: Amazing! And if I want to extend this query with or? (This aggrigate query OR other match)